# Migrate from dev org to partner editon

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, partner-communities, unmanaged-package

How to migrate the triggers and classes and components created in developer edition to the partner org so we can make it into to package. The objective is to make it into a unmanaged package..please advise.

Comment: That's a very broad question you're asking with no simple answer. Migrating the components is one thing, but creating an unmanaged package is another. I suggest you read Andrew Fawcett's Force.com Enterprise Architecture available from Amazon or Pact Publishing.

Answer (score 3):

If your end goal is to create an unmanaged package you shoud be able to do that right in the developer org. For a nice walkthrough go [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging), it walks you through creating a simple class and packing it up in a Developer org.

> To get going, log in to your Developer Environment and then go to
>   Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes to create the class.
>
> Now you're ready to create a package, so navigate to Setup -> Create
>   -> Packages. Hit "New" to start. After providing a name for the package (SimplePackage), you'll be given the opportunity to add
>   package components. Packages are collections of components, and these
>   components range the gamut of the Force.com Platform. For example, you
>   can package an Apex class, a Visualforce page, triggers, email
>   templates, documents and workflow rules (see references at bottom for
>   links to entire list). For this tutorial, click “Add” and select a
>   component type of "Apex Class" and select the SimpleClass defined
>   above. You'll end up with a package definition that looks similar to
>   the following figure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. However, once the package is created, is it possible to upload it as unmanaged package into appexchange ? I understand that for managed package we need to have salesforce partner account. However, with limited license available in developer edition, if we want to create component , app with the objective to publish into appexchange, would it be possible through developer edition ?

Comment: @GaneshKarthick - As a private unlisted app that you can share with a link, haven't done much beyond that.

Comment: @GaneshKarthick there is a new module for creating an app - https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/isv_app_development

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Salesforce ANT Migration Toolkit which is a command line tool to move the metadata from developer org to partner org. It has a package.xml file in which we can specify what components we want to migrate.